# Is ViewBinding set up correctly?

Tags: kotlin, android-viewbinding

My project is not finding the reference to the 1st monster01.

`binding.monster01.setOnClickListener { viewMonsterImage(R.drawable.monster01) }`

Here is the whole section:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

        binding.monster01.setOnClickListener { viewMonsterImage(R.drawable.monster01) }

    }

    private fun viewMonsterImage(monsterId: Int) {
        val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW

        val uri = Uri.parse("http://com.example.myfavoritemonsterviewbinding/view?id=$monsterId")
        intent.data = uri

        intent.putExtra("monsterId", monsterId)

        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

The reference is correct on the layout and I added ViewBinding to Gradle. What am I missing?

Here's a snippet of the layout:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/monster01"
    android:contentDescription="@string/choose"
    android:src="@drawable/monster01"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Comment: If you can see concrete view binding class but it does not contain field referencing your view then there's some problem with layout file itself, maybe post snippet of that.

Comment: I posted a snipper of the layout.

Comment: Is your entire mainactivity just a single imagebutton?

Comment: No, there will be more. I just don't want to go further until I figure how to make this one work.

Comment: We need to see the surrounding code in the xml to tell what might be wrong. Can you post the whole layout code?

Comment: can you show the whole xml for activity and name of layout file?